# how to instantiate class from string in java processing?

Tags: java, processing

I have the car class

```
class car {
...
}
```

then in the rest of the code:

```
ArrayList <Object> cars = new ArrayList <Object> (); // Create an ArrayList object

void draw(){
    String s = "car";
    cars.add(new s());

    try { 
        // If I don't write getClass().getName() gives a classnotfoundException.
        // I think its because i use ide processing.
        cars.add(Class.forName(getClass().getName() + "$car").newInstance());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

I tried this but it gives me an error

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: car_game$car
```

what I mean is  instantiate a class from a string
something like new "car" (), not new car ()

I have a .txt file with the name of several classes.

```
txt file cars.txt
------
car_mo
car_sd
car_dave
----
```

and when loading the .txt I want to instantiate the classes that the .txt has written.

e.g.

```
String[]  txt=loadString("cars.txt")
cars.add (new txt[0]())  //instead of cars.add (new car_mo())
cars.add (new txt[1]())  //instead of cars.add (new car_sd())
```

I am using ide processing, windows7.

Comment: Rephrase your question, not clear at all.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a lot of work for an empty car. ;)

```
package xxx;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class InstantiateFromString {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws InstantiationException, 
            IllegalAccessException, 
            IllegalArgumentException, 
            InvocationTargetException, 
            NoSuchMethodException, 
            SecurityException, 
            ClassNotFoundException 
    {   
        ClassLoader classLoader = InstantiateFromString.class.getClassLoader();
        Class<?> classToInstantiate = classLoader.loadClass("xxx.car");
        Constructor<?> constructor = classToInstantiate.getConstructor();
        Object aCar = constructor.newInstance();
        
        System.out.println(aCar.getClass());
    }
}

class car{
    public car() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to create `car` instances, not `String`s. Also, a bit of explanation makes for better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated it to instantiate a car, although I expect my car is different from the OP's car.

Comment: It uses reflection to 1. find the class, 2. find the zero-argument constructor 3. call the constructor to create an instance.